# How to add values to a double array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, io

I wrote a similar question earlier. However, I have one error I cannot solve now.

I am trying to write a code in C so that if I have a file reg2.dat as such:

```
5.1 3.5 1.4
4.9 3 1.4
4.7 3.2 1.3
4.6 3.1 1.5
5 3.6 1.4
```

Then, I can 1) determine the number of rows (in this case 5), 2) determine the number of columns (in this case 3), 3) write all 15 values in a double array X.

I have my code working for the first two goals. However, I cannot get the double array X to contain the values (5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 4.9, 3, 1.4, 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 5, 3.6, 1.4). I have been stuck on this for one week, and have been given advice, but still need more direct help unfortunately :(

Below is my complete and ordered code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getCol(char *myStr);
int getRow(char *fileName);
int assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *X, char *fileName);

int main(){
   FILE *f;
   char myStr[1000];
   int strL;
   int nCol;
   int nRow;
   char *fileName = "reg2.dat";
   double *X;

   f = fopen(fileName, "r");
   if (f == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     if (fgets(myStr, 1000, f) != NULL )
       puts(myStr);
     fclose(f);
   }

   strL = strlen(myStr);
   nCol = getCol(myStr);
   nRow = getRow(fileName);
   printf("Sample size and number of predictors are %d and %d respectively.\n", nRow, nCol-1);

   X = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * (nRow* nCol));
   assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *X, char *fileName);
   return 0;
}
```

The helper function that does not work follows...

```
int assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *X, char *fileName){
  int i=0;
  int j;
  char string[1000];
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  while(fgets(string, sizeof string, f) != NULL){
    for (j=0; j<nCol; j++){
       strcpy(X[i], strtok(string, " "));
       i++;
    }  
  }

  for (i=0;i<(nRow*nCol);i++){
    printf("%d\n", X[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The helper functions that do work follows...

```
int getCol(char *myStr){
    int length,i,count=0;
    char prev;
    length=strlen(myStr);
    if(length > 0){
      prev = myStr[0];
    }
    for(i=0; i<=length; i++){
      if(myStr[i]==' ' && prev != ' '){
        count++;
      }
      prev = myStr[i];
    }
    if(count > 0 && myStr[i] != ' '){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int getRow(char *fileName){
  char ch;
  int count=0;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  while(!feof(f)){
    ch = fgetc(f);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
fclose(f);
return count;
}
```

Here is the error when I run:

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic readReg.c -o readReg -llapack -lblas -lgfortran
```

Error:

```
readReg.c: In function ‘main’:
readReg.c:40: error: expected expression before ‘int’
readReg.c: In function ‘assignX’:
readReg.c:55: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘strcpy’
/usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘double’
```

Comment: `strcpy` won't work because `X[i]` is a double not a char* which is what `strcpy` expects.

Comment: I advise a look at `strtod()`, in particular its second argument.

Comment: Thank you. So what do you suggest I do? I am going to have to use matrix multiplication with this double array X.

Comment: Where does `assignX` get called? I'm not seeing it above. If you're planning on doing matrix multiplication then I'd say you want to keep the array as a double and not convert to string format.

Comment: Thanks @BinaryJudy. I added that line back in (I removed it for debugging), although I think it introduces another error. I am not sure how much work it would be to do you advice as keeping the array as a double and not converting to string format. I am very terrible at I/O and am not sure if there would be a simple way to redo all that :o(

Comment: @user2808302 Please see my answer below. Although you now have `assignXY` which I'm assuming is different from `assignX`. Are you trying to do a 2D array or just two separate arrays?

Comment: @BinaryJudy. Sorry. I just updated that! I am only trying 1D array separately. However, with the code, I am getting two errors on line 40 (readReg.c:40: error: expected expression before ‘int’
readReg.c:40: error: too few arguments to function ‘assignX’). I know the function is a void function, and I am supposed to return 0. I did that, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Just a silly mistake if you are trying to compile what you edited above. Where you are calling `assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *X, char *fileName);` should be `assignX(nCol, nRow, X, fileName);`

Comment: I am very new to C, and have more experience in other languages. I keep doing that and then being stunned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use `atof` instead of `strcpy` to convert you `char *`value to the `double` value?

I mean change this
`strcpy(X[i], strtok(string, " "));`

to this
`X[i] = atof(strtok(string, " "));`

Here you have an example
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm

UPDATE:

Here you have the function AssignX working (the last line in the file **reg2.dat** must have an enter (`\n`), if the last line does not have an enter the program will crash because the row number will be 4 instead of 5.  I recommend you detect that case to avoid the program crashing :D)

```
int assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *X, char *fileName){
  int i=0;
  int j;
  char string[1000];
  char* data = NULL;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), f) != NULL){
    data = strtok(string, " ");
    for (j=0; NULL != data && j<nCol; j++){
        if (data[strlen(data) - 1] == '\n')
            data[strlen(data) - 1] = '\0';
        X[i] = atof(data);
        data = strtok(NULL, " ");
       i++;
    } 
  }  

  for (i=0;i<(nRow*nCol);i++){
    printf("%f\n", X[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Another option would be to use [fscanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) and scan in the values from the file.

Comment: @CrApHeR. Thank you! Just a quick question. When I do what you did (and what I did too), I notice that I am only getting the first token from each line and repeating it three times. Instead, I want to record all three tokens for each line. In other words, I want to use the j index I set up in the lines surrounding what you helped me with.

Comment: @CrApHeR. Specifically these lines:   while(fgets(string, sizeof string, f) != NULL){
    for (j=0; j<nCol; j++){
       X[i]=atof(strtok(string," "));
       i++;
    }
  }

Comment: @CrApHer. I would just want the first three characters in the output to be (5.1 3.5 1.4) instead of what I have now of (5.1 5.1 5.1)

Comment: Yes, that is because your are not applying the offset of the already copied data to the string. Let me edit my answer to give you a better explanation.

Comment: @CrApHeR. Thanks so much! I would really appreciate that! I have really been stuck on this for too long of a time!

Comment: Helps very very much! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line, as the compiler tells you, is wrong:

```
strcpy(X[i], strtok(string, " "));
```

In terms of syntax, the first argument to `strcpy` needs to be a `char*`. `X[i]` is not a `char*`.

In terms of functionality, that is not how you extract a `double` from a string. You need to use `atof` or `sscanf`.

Here's an updated loop that should work:

```
// Declare this at the start of the function.
char* token;

...

while(fgets(string, sizeof string, f) != NULL)
{
   // Use string to start the call to strtok.
   token = strtok(string, " ");

   // Even though each row should have nCol, be safe
   // and make sure that you don't process token if
   // it is NULL.
   for ( j = 0; j < nCol && token != NULL; j++)
   {
      X[i] = atof(token);
      i++;

      // For subsequent calls to strtok, use NULL
      // for the first argument.
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, which should result in an array of doubles from the file:

```
  int assignX(double *X, char *fileName){
  int i=0;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  while(fscanf(f, "%lf", &(X[i])) != EOF) 
       i++; 
  }
```